# In Wilson's Theorem Why can we always split integers into mutually inverse pairs?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I mean for example $p=13$

$1*12\equiv-1 \pmod{13}$

then inverse pairs

$2*7\equiv1\pmod{13}$

$3*9\equiv1\pmod{13}$

$4*10\equiv1\pmod{13}$

$5*8\equiv1\pmod{13}$

$6*11\equiv1\pmod{13}$

Comment: $1*12 \equiv -1 \pmod {13}, \quad\;2*7 \equiv 1 \pmod {13}\;$ etc. You can always pair $a$ with its inverse $a^{-1}$.

Comment: Can you check your signs??

Comment: So what is with 5 and 8 ?

Comment: With 5 and 8 it is 1, thats correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ be an odd prime.  We make the following claim:  for any positive integer $a \in \{1, 2, \ldots, p-1\}$, there exists exactly one $b \in \{1, 2, \ldots, p-1\}$ such that $ab \equiv 1 \pmod p$.

Proof.  First, we show existence:  for a given $a$, construct the set $$S = \{1a, 2a, \ldots, (p-1)a\} \pmod p.$$  Suppose none of the elements of $S$ is congruent to $1$:  then since $S \subseteq \{1, 2, \ldots, p-1\}$ by definition (it is not possible for any element of $S$ to be congruent to $0 \pmod p$ since that would contradict the primality of $p$), it follows by the Pigeonhole Principle that there exist two elements of $S$ that are congruent to each other modulo $p$; i.e., there exist $k \ne k'$ such that $$ka \equiv k'a \pmod p.$$  But this would also imply $(k-k')a \equiv 0 \pmod p$, which is again a contradiction.  Therefore, there exists an element of $S$ congruent to $1 \pmod p$, and we have proven existence.

Next, we show uniqueness.  Suppose there exist $b \ne b'$ such that $$ab \equiv ab' \equiv 1 \pmod p.$$  Then $a(b-b') \equiv 0 \pmod p$, and since $b - b' \ne 0$ by supposition, again we have a contradiction.  Therefore such a $b$ is unique for a given $a$.

From this basic proof, we can also see that these $\{a,b\}$ pairs are disjoint from the earlier argument by contradiction.  For if $ab \equiv 1 \pmod p$ and $ac \equiv 1 \pmod p$, then $a(b-c) \equiv 0 \pmod p$, thus $b = c$, thus two pairs are either disjoint, or equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

I assume $p$ is an odd prime. Then you have the residues 1,2,..,p-1. Now very $a \in \{1,.., p-1\}$ has an inverse $a^{-1}$ with $a a^{-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p.\; $But $a\equiv 1 \pmod p$ and $a\equiv -1\equiv p-1 \pmod p$ are self-inverse (and they are the only two roots of unity), and the remaining $p-3$ residues come in pairs with  $a a^{-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p,\,$ and $a \not \equiv a^{-1} \pmod p$. Therefore $(p-1)! \pmod p$ is the product $$(p-1)! \equiv (1)(-1)\prod_{k=1}^{\frac{p-3}{2}}1 \equiv -1\pmod p$$

Note: For $p=13\;$ you have the roots of unity 1 and 12, as well as the pairs (2,7), (3,9), (4,10), (5,8), and (6,11).

Comment: Why do the remaining $p-3$ residues come in pairs ?

Comment: @derivative: As already said, because every remaining $a$ has a unique $a^{-1}$ and $a\not \equiv a^{-1},\;$ and the pairs are $(a, a^{-1}).$